# Segmentation Fault on Assigning string Array

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have been trying to return an array of strings for a function for a couple of days to no avail. While I was searching around StackOverflow, I found that it would be a better idea to have a parameter that will be assigned the value of an array. So, here is my code example (not the actual usage, but a mockup of how I am trying to use the function). I am sorry if the code is a bit sloppy. I have been testing things out with it for a while.

```
void splitOn(string message, string delim, string***toCh) {

string** rString = new string*;
string lArr[numberOf(message, delim)+1];
for(int index=0; index<numberOf(message, delim)+2; index++) {

    lArr[index]=message.substr(0, message.find(delim)).c_str();

    message = message.substr(message.find(delim)+1, message.length());
rString[index]=&lArr[index];

cout << "IN LOOP "<<*rString[index]<<endl;
}
rString[numberOf(message, string(delim))] = &message;
toCh=&rString;
}

int main(){
string***arr;
splitOn("fox.over.lazy.dog", ".", arr);
cout << **arr[0]<<endl;
```

Note:

- numberOf() takes a string and a delimiter(string) and returns how many times the delimiter is found within the string.
- strings are from std::string
- lArr (the local array within the loop) and *rString all give correct output.
- Although I am trying to assign the array to a parameter, learning how to return an array is more appealing to me.

I could hack this together with a file and getLine(), but I would prefer to learn how to properly do this.

Comment: You're already using `std::string`. Go for `std::vector` while you're at it. I'm also not sure why you have a `string ***`.

Comment: No use of `***` can be good in a sane C++ program... use a `std::vector<std::string>` if you need a dynamic collection of strings.

Comment: @chris I would use std::vector, but I would prefer to use arrays as I plan on rewriting this in C and would like to fundamentally understand why this does not work.

Comment: @Dymatic: It fundamentally doesn't work because it's fundamentally messed up ;).  Q: Would you prefer an example in C, or in C++.  If C++, then use "vector<string>".  No "c_str()", no "***" nonsense.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you for telling me about the c_str(). I forgot I had left that in there. After resolving that issue the code still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return local variables, which will never work. You and your caller need to agree on how to allocate the return value. In C++ as the commenters mention this would normally be done by passing a reference to a vector to handle your allocation for you.

In C you have two options, you can either get the caller to pass in a big enough allocation, or use multiple calls to malloc in the callee (not forgetting the calls to free in the caller!)

For instance, if you pass a writable character array, you can simply overwrite the separator characters with null characters to split it up into individual strings without having to allocate new copies.

Comment: You were correct. The problem was caused by the local variables, so I made the string global and it works.